# I want a detail view of report on my error, Struts 2 and Spring

Tags: spring, jsp, debugging, struts2

I am trying to debug my problem but my project keeps trying to find an error.jsp file for custom error page. It happens that the project is a copy of another project which uses a custom error page for displaying their error page. Which doesn't tell me anything about my problem. So where do you think this mapping of error.jsp file to my errors located in a struts 2 and spring integrated project?

```
HTTP Status 404 - /project/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp
```

Comment: In your struts.xml, add the constant <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/> to display more details when debugging errors. Then tell us what you get when you add this constant. We will also need to see your struts.xml file and the hierarchy of your app directory. It may be a mapiing issue. Help us to help you!

Comment: the stuts.devMode has a true value i just checked it.

Comment: Just grep for `error.jsp`

Answer (score 0):

There are many thing they could have done. So here are general ideas:

All the exceptions which need to handle, mapped  in struts.xml

```
    <global-exception-mappings>

        <exception-mapping
            exception=java.lang.Exception"
            result="error.internal" />
    </global-exception-mappings>
```

Then add the result to the error.jsp or another action with chain

```
        <result name="error.internal" type="chain">
                        <param name="actionName">error-manager</param>
                        <param name="namespace">/common</param>
                    </result>
     <!-- OR -->
    <result name="error.internal" type="redirect">/error.jsp</result>
```

After that review your web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/common/error-manager.action</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
<exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/common/error-manager.action</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: I found that you want to remove error page. Am I right?! So remove above from web.xml or struts.xml

Comment: I already have commented out the web.xml file that you have posted before running the application.  And I couldn't find the code that you have posted in my struts.xml file. That's why I asked if i could add it or not.

Comment: Lets ask again. Do you want to have your own error.jsp in the way that it shows the correct information? OR do you want to find why the application forwards to error.jsp and remove it, so your application always shows struts default error page? Which one are you looking for?!

Comment: remove all mentioned error-page tags from web.xml and remove all mentioned global-exception-mappings and also exception-mappings from struts.xml